# Ember.JS Tutorial "Super-Rentals" and API Paths

Tags: ember.js

I've been following the SuperRentals Ember.JS tutorial and have also cloned the finished product from [here](https://github.com/ember-learn/super-rentals).

I'm struggling to identify where we define that we retrieve data from rentals.json in <app_dir>/public/api:

> XXX@XXXX-XX:~/super-rentals/public/api$ ls
> rentals  rentals.json

If I change rentals.json to another name, the site stops loading entirely implying some configuration or code requires changing to reflect this.

However, when I grep for "rentals" recursively in <app_dir>/app none of the references returned appear related.

Is this naming picked up by convention, or is it explicitly defined somewhere in the application?

Answer (score 0):

[Per the Ember CLI docs](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/folder-layout/):

> `public/` – This directory will be copied verbatim into the root of the built application. Use this for assets that don’t have a build step, such as images or fonts

Normally in an Ember app, we use this to provide static assets like images or fonts, as the docs indicate. However, in this case, we're taking advantage of the fact that the JSON file used for the tutorial *is* static. When Ember CLI builds your app, it copies `public/api/rentals.json` into `dist/api/rentals.json`. (You can customize where the build output goes, but by default it's `dist`.)

Then, when any web server serves the files in `dist`, they're available to request from the server. The Ember dev server is serving all the files from `/dist`, including the Ember app itself, but *also* including `dist/api/rentals.json`, which means you can do `fetch('/api/rentals.json')` and get that blob of data back.

Ember Data also has niceties that allow you to take that `fetch` and turn it into something which looks a bit more like an ORM: you can define a model which maps to the API resources. (This works most easily if you're using [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/), but with the flexibility to support *most* REST or REST-ish APIs if you need). Once you define those, you ask for them by the name corresponding to the model, using Ember's conventional layout. In the tutorial, this ends up defining a `rental` model to go along with the `rentals` "API endpoint". Combined with the Ember Data `store` service, instead of writing `fetch('/api/rentals.json')`, you write `this.store.findAll('rental')`.

If Ember Data isn't the right fit for your back end, you can of course keep using `fetch` directly, or drop in [Axios](https://axios-http.com) as a customizable layer on *top* of `fetch`, or use a GraphQL client, etc. – the tutorial shows Ember Data as a good "out of the box" option, but it is not at all required for Ember.

Comment: This makes sense - thank-you. However, I can't see "fetch" calls from any of the code in the cloned Git repository, so I'm still unsure where in Ember.JS we're saying "get the contents of *this particular* file (rentals.json)".

Comment: @Masutatsu ah, you're looking at the final work product and yes, some Ember-esque niceties have been applied. If you take a look at https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-1/working-with-data/, you'll see the introduction of the `rentals.json` file using `fetch` to retrieve it. Then in https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-2/ember-data/ you'll see the simplification of the routing / loading to use Ember Data instead of strictly fetch, while still mapping to retrieve the same `rentals.json` file. Does that make more sense?